# IPython doesn't answer when calling self-defined function

Tags: while-loop, runtime-error, ipython

```
def nast(L):
   i=len(L)-1
   while L != [1 for i in range(len(L))]:
      if L[i]==0:
         L[i]=1
         break
      i=i-1
   for j in range(i+1,len(L)):
      L[j]=0
   return L  

L = [0,0,1,0,1]
```

I would like to give this function 'L' list, but when I do this, I get nothing, IPython kernel seems to be frozen; when I use "Interrupt current kernet" option, I get:

```
KeyboardInterrupt                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-000635d72af9> in <module>()
----> 1 nast(L)

<ipython-input-1-7918814a171f> in nast(L)
      1 def nast(L):
      2    i=len(L)-1
----> 3    while L != [1 for i in range(len(L))]:
      4       if L[i]==0:
      5          L[i]=1

KeyboardInterrupt:
```

I wonder what is wrong, thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
while L != [1 for i in range(len(L))]:
```

The `i` variable leaks out of the list comprehension, so after that line, `i` is always `len(L)-1`, and your while loop is always checking the last item in `L`.

This was fixed in Python 3, so your code works there (at least, it finishes - I don't know if it's doing what you expect). To do it in Python 2, you'll need to call one of your `i` variables something else.